# Display message while editing a node in drupal?

Tags: drupal

I want to display a message while editing a node in drupal like this "we are updating this page, we will get back to u soon"
can anyone help me!

Comment: Do you have a custom module for the site, or are you just configuring modules that are already built?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an unpublished revision to do this.  Make the current published revision your message that says "we are updating this page" and then have an unpublished revision that contains the content you're working on.  You have to edit the content type to turn off "Published" under workflow settings and check "Create new revision" in order to create your revisioning workflow.  The [Revisioning module](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) can help a lot with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) that trigger an action like "content is going to be view" (possibly with some condition) and display a message to the user.